# How to pass rx/tx led outputs to a shield

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, led, shields

I have an Arduino Uno. I am building a custom shield and was wondering how I would connect two of the LEDs on the shield to the TX / RX LEDs on the Uno. Digital pins 0 and 1 seem obvious, but after further research, it appears that they are not for this.

In better terms, I want two LEDs on my shield that replicate the TX / Rx LEDs on the Arduino Uno.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TX/RX LEDs on the Uno are not connected to the main MCU but are instead connected to the USB communication chip, be it a FTDI or ATmega16U2. You would need to solder wires to the appropriate connections on the board and then connect them to the shield in question.

Answer (score 2):

If you need just indicate data on TX/RX you can make simple circuit on shield bound to TX/RX lines.

[image]